# Moved from bash to zsh - some commands / binaries not recognised

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, linux-mint

I've recently started using zsh. I notice some commands which work in bash no longer work in zsh. In particular, I'm using *virtualenv* with *virtualenvwrapper* for Python virtual environments, which has the command *workon* to change the current virtual environment. When I run bash, it recognises this command, but when running zsh, this command is not recognised.

Where does the shell look for these binaries? How can I point zsh to this binary when I use this or similar commands?

To clarify, my default shell is now zsh, when I enter *bash* to start running bash, the command is recognised, and when I enter *zsh* it is no longer recognised. The path is therefore the same when running both commands

Running Linux Mint 19.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `workon` is defined in a script to be *sourced* by the shell.
With bash, you typically edit `.bashrc` or `.profile` to make it happen whenever the shell is opened.

You can do the same for zsh, but you need to carry over the lines from the file you edited to a different file, e.g. `.zprofile`.

See https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile and https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html for more information.

Comment: @mcindoe : Also, depending on what you did in your .bashrc, pay attention to syntactic and semantic differences between bash and zsh. I usually keep those lines which work identical in bash and zsh, in a separate file (say : `.commonrc`) which I source from .bahrc and .zshrc.